# Simple Bash-C communication

Tags: c, bash, unix, stdout

I'm trying to build a script that will respond to a simple C program. I guess the scripts needs to read line by line and parse the text until it finds the question. Then it has to reply to the same stdout. The script reads in at an infinite loop, and i start it on the command line

```
./script.sh &
```

in order to have it running in the background. Then, in the same terminal, i start my C programm that outputs on the command line and waits at a scanf.
My problem is that it looks as if those two processes are interacting with a different stdout since they can't "see" eachother. Obviously i have misunderstood something...any help?

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( ; ; )) do
    while read line; do
        if [ "$line" == ">" ] then
        echo "yes"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix) (add the right parenthesis manually in the address bar -- SO's regexp for URLs has problems)

Answer (score 2):

What about using [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) ? Expect is a Unix tool to programmatically reply to interactive applications, incredibly useful to solve problems like your. Of course you can use it in a bash script.

The answer to your problem will look similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect << EOF
  spawn simple_c_application
  expect ">"
  send "yes\r"
  expect eof
EOF
```

The script will spawn your application, check the output for you and reply **yes** when the output line *contains* **>**. You can also use anchors in your expect pattern: the character `^` matches the beginning of the line and `$` the end. So `^>$` matches only when the line is *exactly* **>**.

You'll just have to install expect from your package manager and then use the bash script as always.

Comment: Thanx but I need to do that with a bash script. It's just a test application for something bigger But actually, my problem is how I can do that with two applications running in the same terminal.

Comment: You can :) I'll post you the complete script in a minute

Comment: And yes it works! :-) However I don't want the script to start the application...

Answer (score 1):

Create a socket file with `mkfifo` and from the script read from this socket file instead of the `stdin`.
From your C program open the socket with `open` and just write to this instead of stdout.

Example:

In a terminal type this to create a socket file.

```
user~$ mkfifo mysocket
```

Change your script to this:

```
while :
do
    here=$(<mysocket)
    if [ "$here" == ">" ] then
        echo "yes"
    fi
done
```

and in your c file

```
char* test = ">\n";
int mysocket = open("/home/user/mysocket","w");
int byteswrite = write(mysocket,(void*)test,2);
```

run the script first and after your program

Comment: Technically, mkfifo makes fifos, not sockets.

Comment: It doesn't look to work for me but I don't have time to debug now. The idea is that I use a socket for both app and script instead of the stdout. That's clear. I will work on that. Thanx for the reply. Although I would like to avoid the socket thing.

Comment: i edited the script section where it reads from the file because didn't work for me with `read` ... as is now it works for me